# JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError when accessing a smaller array than the last load

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I am very new to JavaScript (been programming Arduinos and Python for some time now) and have been following a tutorial for making a calendar showing events for 1 month at a time.
When not populating the calendar, there is no issues.

When populating the calendar with events (work schedule for a fire dept., so I'm afraid I cant show pictures of the project), I get a Uncaught TypeError when accessing information in an array shorter than the previous (being that February has less days than January, hence reading from an array with a length of 28 instead of a length of 31).
When I console.log() it, the first 28 reads just fine, after that the error comes event though I wouldn't expect it to look for more instances than the 28

Now, the js just jQueries the entire years worth of data into an array when loading the page - it come from at database on another server.

Then, when loading the page, my calendar starts at the month we're currently in. From there, you can go to next month or the previous month and so forward.
Every time the month is changed, a function named load() is called, updating the month.
What I've build in, is a new function loading a new set of events for the next month loading.

```
function findMaanedsEvents(maaned) {
    let maanedens_events = [];
    let eventtaeller = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < requestdata.length; i++) {
        let reqm = requestdata[i]['dato'].split('-');
        if (reqm[1] == maaned) {
            maanedens_events[eventtaeller] = requestdata[i];
            eventtaeller ++;
        }
    }
    return maanedens_events;
}
```

requestdata is the result of the jQuery. The return is saved into an array and is working just fine. It returns the right set of data and the correct length.

The month showing part of it works just fine. It's the event part that's not behaving.

with 'nav' being the integer that holds the number for which month we want displayed, I try to populate using the data like so:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= paddingDays + daysInMonth; i++) {
    const daySquare = document.createElement('div');
    daySquare.classList.add('day');
    if (i > paddingDays) {
        daySquare.innerText = i - paddingDays;
        dagens_events = 
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['bm1'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['bm2'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['bm3'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['bm4'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['bm5'];
        const eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
        if (dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['helligdag'] == 1) {
            eventDiv.classList.add('helligdag_event');
        }
        else {
            eventDiv.classList.add('event');
        }        
        eventDiv.innerText = dagens_events;
        daySquare.appendChild(eventDiv);
        console.log(dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]['bm1']);
    }
    else {
        daySquare.classList.add('padding');
    }
    calendar.appendChild(daySquare);
}
```

As mentioned, this works fine if the month being loaded has an equal or greater number of days.
If it has less though, I get this console.log:
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUtIX.png)
'bm1' being 1 of 5 names showing as 1 event for the day - I just logged it for debugging purposes. The red lines is just the names for the 'bm1' key that I've blurred out.

At first, I though the issue was that my array had too many indexes, the last ones just empty. But by console.logging it, I see that the length of the array matches the number of days in the month for every load that I do.

I've tried fiddling around and Googling. I've tried going away for a while to come back and have another go at it, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

As I noted, I am very new to JavaScript and it could be me overlooking something completely basic - bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - sorry for asking, but I've been trying for hours without luck.

It turned out that even though the array was returned with only the 28 days for february, the 3 last (28-31 january) was in fact still indexed in the array, even though it was not containing anything.

The solution was to put the codeblock inside an if-statement checking for content of the xth row in the event array and only firing with it was not undefined.

Like so:

```
if (dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1] != undefined) {
    daySquare.innerText = i - paddingDays;
    const dagens_events = 
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]?.['bm1'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]?.['bm2'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]?.['bm3'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]?.['bm4'] + "\n" +
        dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]?.['bm5'];
    const eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
    if (dagsevents[i - paddingDays - 1]?.['helligdag'] == 1) {
        eventDiv.classList.add('helligdag_event');
    }
    else {
        eventDiv.classList.add('event');
    }
    eventDiv.classList.add('event');
    eventDiv.innerText = dagens_events;
    daySquare.appendChild(eventDiv);
}
```

I dont know if my answer is beneficial to anyone, but here it is.

I'm sure there's much cleaner and smoother ways to go about this problem. I'm still learning overall in programming an especially in Javascript.
Therefore, please let me know if you got a smoother and/or better solution to this problem :)

Cheers.